# Eslint: a rule for new lines for a function body' brackets (similar to object-curly-newline)?

Tags: eslint

I'd like a function body's brackets to have new lines:

```
const fn = () => { // new line here


}; // new line before
```

The same goes for `function`.

We have https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-newline
for object, can't find the same for functions.
Maybe there're several rules to achieve that?
Any help would be appreciated.