# How to make ESLint fix the closing bracket's whitespace? (with either object-curly-newline: consistent or another rule)

Tags: eslint

Consider the following code:

```
merge(config.tasks, {
    save: { text: "save", tooltip: "Save your changes to this TiddlyWiki" },
    // ...
    plugins: { text: "plugins", tooltip: "Manage installed plugins", content: '<<plugins>>' } });
```

I want ESLint to forbid such syntax, and the desired syntax should be

```
merge(config.tasks, {
    save: { text: "save", tooltip: "Save your changes to this TiddlyWiki" },
    // ...
    plugins: { text: "plugins", tooltip: "Manage installed plugins", content: '<<plugins>>' }
});
```

Now, adding this to .eslintrc:

```
    "object-curly-newline": ["error", { "consistent": true }],
```

does highlight the first case as an error and accepts the second one. The problem is, autofix doesn't work this way: instead, it does this:

```
merge(config.tasks, { save: { text: "save", tooltip: "Save your changes to this TiddlyWiki" },
    // ...
    plugins: { text: "plugins", tooltip: "Manage installed plugins", content: '<<plugins>>' } });
```

My question is: can I somehow configure the rule to make the fix work as described, or may be use another rule for this?

PS a side note: `"array-bracket-newline": ["error", "consistent"]` fixes the similar issue correctly, not sure why there's a difference.

Comment: i have a similar problem with functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440147/eslint-a-rule-for-new-lines-for-a-function-body-brackets-similar-to-object-cu